# Resize / positioning issue preparing custom google map for print media

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on setting up a print button for a custom google map. My end goal is to have my map resize to 800px x 800px on print so the viewable area of the map fits on paper regardless of the size of your device.

The resize piece of this is working just fine but when trying to recenter the map it only changes after the print window has been triggered. Am I missing a refresh on the map that's required or is there something obvious that I'm just not seeing.

Thanks in advance!

Broken Code;

```
  function center_print() {
    var lastPos = map.getCenter();
      document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = "800px";
      document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.width = "800px";
    map.setCenter(lastPos);
    window.print();
      document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = "";
      document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.width = "";
    map.setCenter(lastPos);
  }
```

Final Solution;

```
  //Used for centering the map on print
  function center_map(size) {
  lastPos = map.getCenter(); 
  if (lastPos != null) {  
    document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = size + "px";
    document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.width = size + "px";
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(lastPos);
  return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
  }

  function print_map() {
     if (center_map(800)) {
      window.setTimeout(window.print, 1000);
      document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = "";
      document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.width = "";
     }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using a business licence? AFAIK printing a map with custom markers overlayed is forbidden by the licence agreement.

Comment: This piece has no markers on it. Just trying to find the center of the map on resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest triggering a re-size on the map itself after re-sizing the map like so:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

This should retain the center from the original size I believe.

Comment: This essentially did the trick, I did have to modify some of the original code as my window.print() was firing too early. Thanks!